# is netlink synchronous or asynchronous protocol?

Tags: asynchronous, linux-kernel, netlink

I was reading various resources about `netlink`, and they all say that the `netlink` communication protocol is `asynchronous` (example: https://www.opensourceforu.com/2015/08/netlink-a-communication-mechanism-in-linux/), however this confuses me: I think only events notification mechanism of `netlink` is asynchronous, while request messages are sent/received synchronously.

Am I wrong?